# "exec('sh foo.sh')" in PHP not working

Tags: php, linux, apache, bash, shell

I've recently set up my Apache2 Server on my Linux machine. Now I've wanted to execute a PHP script (index.php), which runs a shell script (foo.sh), which creates a folder in my home directory, but the directory was not created.

These are the original two files:

foo.sh:

```
#!bin/bash

mkdir /home/lorenzo/testDir
```

index.php:

```
<?php

exec('sh test.sh');

?>
```

So, I thought maybe the problem occurs because of privileges or something, and indeed after I changed the files to that:

foo.sh:

```
#!bin/bash

echo "Hello world"
```

index.php:

```
<?php

$temp=exec('sh test.sh');
echo $temp;

?>
```

I saw the output `Hello World` on my website.

So the PHP script is executed and it runs the shell script. But why can't the shell script execute the mkdir command?

Comment: The Apache user probably doesn't have permission to write to your home directory.

Comment: Be very careful -- you could be exposing yourself to the "shellshocked" bug!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indeed is most likely a permission issue.

You first have to figure out which user apache runs at. This is usually `www-data` (on Debian-ish Linuxes, such as Ubuntu) or `apache` (on RedHat-ish Linuxes) or something along the lines. A `ps -eF | grep apache` will reveal the user.

After you figured that out, make sure that the apache user has the appropriate rights in your home directory. You can either add it to your user group (using `usermod -a -G ...` and then `chmod g+w ~`) or allow writing for *all* users (`chmod o+w ~`).

**But**, both of this is a *bad* idea. Your php script (or anything else running as the apache user) can be broken into and cracked, leaving you home directory open for malicious attackers to modify and `rm -rf`.

In addition, if you’re running a RedHat-ish Linux, you *will* run into SELinux which by defaut prevents apache from accessing user directories at all. In that case, you also have to set `setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs on`.

**Instead**, I would recommend that you use a different directory and give your user full access to that. Something along the lines of `/var/www/testDir` with the apache as owner and group, and adding yourself to the apache user group is probably a sane idea.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a permission issue. Make sure that Apache has write permission to that directory

Answer (score -1):

You may have permission issues on the server. Try to use `chmod -R 775 <dirname>(or 777)` in your ssh command line. You can do this in php code with `chmod()` too but I don't suggest you because it would run it everytime the php code runs and changing it more times is pointless. It can output to the screen but I bet the directory the script wants to make file has permission 755. Try to check it.

Comment: The PHP code won’t be allowed to do ``chmod`` on the destination. The destination is in ``/home``, which is (on any sanely configured Linux) something like ``drwxr-xr-x root root``. No apache user (except if apache is running as root and without SELinux, which is not the case, otherwise it would be allowed to write in ``/home/lorenzo``) is allowed to change anything in there.

Comment: @JonasWielicki I meant there is a function in php too. But did you try the FIRST solution in my answer? In the ssh shell(if it runs on external server) you must be able to change the permissions from terminnal. If it runs from your machine, you can do `sudo chmod -R 775 <targetdir>' or `sudo -i` then chmod. Note: `sudo -i` grants you root permissions if you are defined as sudoer so I suggest you do it that way.

Comment: I know that from the shell, it will work (otherwise, I would have downvoted). I just wanted to remark that you can’t do that from the PHP script.